# Conditionally add CSS file in layout XML (local.xml)

Tags: layout, magento-1, theme, configuration

I need to add a CSS file in local.xml based on some custom variables. I have 5 CSS files but each time only one needs to be loaded.

I only know how to check if a single variable is set in the config. If config returns TRUE, the CSS file will be loaded in the frontend:

```
<action method="addItem" ifconfig="my_module/settings/variable"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/a.css</name><params/></action>
```

So for now I must put my code in **head.phtml** in app\design\frontend\my_theme\default\template\page\html\ to load CSS files like this:

```
<?php
  $my_var = Mage::helper('my_module/my_helper')->getFileName();
?>
<link href="<?php echo $my_var; ?>.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

But it has a drawback: my CSS files will not be merged by Magento's CSS/JS merge function.

**So, is there any way to do the same but inside local.xml?** Is there any way to call a method from the helper which would return the name of the CSS file which should be loaded (based on some calculations inside that helper)?

**SOLUTION CANDIDATE** :)

I tried something similar to what Alan Storm described in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601579/1647291

I tried this in my local.xml file:

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name helper="my_module/my_helper/getFileName" />
    <params/>
</action>
```

Helper method getFileName() returns file name `a.css`. **But Magento searches for that CSS file inside "base" theme, not in the current theme**. Magento loads CSS file with this path:

> http://example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/a.css

So my file name is prefixed with **example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/**. But the correct path should be:

> http://example.com/skin/frontend/my_theme/default/a.css

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bottom line: you need to have a value calculated by PHP, therefore the approach of using a helper is appropriate. I think it makes sense to use the `addCss` convenience method rather than `addItem` a it's a little cleaner and should work fine for your needs:

```
<{handle}>
    <action block="head" method="addCss">
        <stylesheet helper="my_module/my_helper/getFileName" />
    </action>
</{handle}>
```

Your helper seems to be calculating the path to the CSS files using the design model, but this will be done again by the `page/html_head` block. Change your helper to simply return the file paths relative to the theme (i.e. *not* using the design model) and your problem is solved.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. although my css is in `skin/frontend/default/mytheme/css/my.css` and I'm returning `css/my.css` from helper method, still the css was not loaded. Can you post some code snippet from helper method?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal is your handle being loaded? Is your theme active?

Comment: Yes. my theme is active and the method was written in `Helper/Data.php` and the module is working.

Comment: And if you include it manually in the `<default>` handle and just setting it normally by just specifying the path + name does it work?

Comment: yes. if in my module's layout xml I add it as: `<reference name="head"><action method="addCss"><style>css/my.css</style></action></reference>`. this works.

Comment: @MohammadFaisal - okay, you should ask this in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that the solution described in my question actually works. I just did a stupid mistake. This code was added to **local.xml** in my theme:

```
<action method="addItem">
    <type>skin_css</type>
    <name helper="my_module/my_helper/getFileName" />
    <params/>
</action>
```

Helper method getFileName() returns file name `a.css`. But my CSS file wasn't in the correct directory:

> http://example.com/skin/frontend/my_theme/default/a.css

so Magento tried to find that file inside "base" theme, not in the current theme:

> http://example.com/skin/frontend/base/default/a.css

So if file is in the correct directory, all will work as expected. The code posted by @benmarks will also work:

```
<action method="addCss">
    <stylesheet helper="my_module/my_helper/getFileName" />
</action>
```